# Rolling a die $1000$ times, there is a time interval such that the product of all the results in that interval is a cube of $3$.

Tags: combinatorics

Each of the six faces of a die is marked with an integer, not necessarily positive. The die is rolled $1000$ times. Show that there is a time interval such that the product of all rolls in this interval is a cube of an integer. (For example, it could happen that the product of all outcomes between 5th and 20th throws is a cube; obviously, the interval has to include at least one throw!)

I looked at abcdef as a possible product , somehow $1000$ of these 'terms' no matter how we shuffle them , a product like ababab or adadad or acdacdacd will be in the string but i cant prove how :(

Answer (score 12):

We can show something stronger; there exists an interval of rolls where each side has appeared a number of times which is a multiple of $3$.

For each $i=1,2,\dots,1000$, let $a_i$ be number of times that the first face has appeared in rolls numbered $1,2,\dots,i$. Same for $b_i,c_i,d_i,e_i,f_i$. Consider the $1000$ ordered six-tuples of values $T_i:=(a_i,b_i,\dots,f_i)$, where each coordinate is only recorded modulo $3$. There are $3^6=729$ possible six-tuples, and there are $1000$ rolls, so by the pigeonhole principle, there are two indices $i<j$ for which $T_i=T_j$. This implies that among rolls numbered $i+1,i+2,\dots,j$, each face appears a number of times which is a multiple of three.

Comment: i dont get it, how again can u use pigeonhole? and how does this work for cubes not 3k

Comment: (a) There are $1000$ numbers $i\in\{1,2,\dots,1000\}$, and $729$ possible tuples. $1000$ pigeons in $729$ holes. (b) If each face appears a multiple of three times, and the numbers of the faces are $x,y,z,w,s,t$, then the product of the numbers in that interval $[i+1,j]$ is $x^{3i}y^{3j}\cdots t^{3k}$, which is the cube of $x^iy^j\cdots t^k$.

Comment: i get pigeonhole ..1000 into 729 means 3 will be in one pigeonhole right? and thats the cube?

Comment: how do u get the 729 again?

Comment: Do you understand my sentence that starts with “Consider...”? We keep track of the remainder of the number of times each face appears in the first $i$ rolls modulo 3. There are three possible remainders, and six faces, so $3^6$. The reason this is helpful is because if the number of times the $a$ face appears in the first $i$ rolls is $3m+r$, and in the first $j$ rolls is $3n+r$, then subtracting, the number of times $a$ appears after $i$ and up to $j$ is $3(n-m)$, which is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: why are there 3 remainders? the faces can have ANY integers..if the integers could be only 1-3 or 6-9 or 9-12 ect then yes i can see three remainders but here they can be any so will have 9 possible remainders

Comment: Im looking back at this and saying wow i was really dumb ( that day lol) for not seeing this ( as obvious) it shows ive come along way in my careeer as a recreational Mathemagician lol 3 remainders because any more then that would mean divisibility by 3 .

Answer (score 2):

Strengthening the result another way:

For each $i=1,\dots,1000$ let $2^{a_i}\cdot 3^{b_i}\cdot 5^{c_i}$ be the product of the first $i$ rolls. Then there are only $3^3=27$ possible values for the 3-tuple $(a_i\bmod 3, b_i\bmod 3, c_i\bmod 3)$, so, by a pigeonhole principle argument similar to Mike Earnest's in his answer, a cube must appear if there are more than 27 rolls.

Comment: The question specifies that the sides of the die might be numbered with _any_ integers, not necessarily just 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. I believe the worst case would be one where each side is numbered with a distinct prime.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen OK, good point, now that I see that in the OP.